# Filetype icon not being displayed when downloading something in Chrome

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, icons, browser

Whenever I download something in Chrome, the little icon in the center of the download that shows the file type icon, around which there's the download progress bar, isn't displayed. If that sounds confusing, take a look at this screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/q6mRp.png]

Comment: Only for `deb` files?

Comment: @RobinJ Sorry for the late reply, but like BrownE said, it's with all files I download with Chrome.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report with Google.

Comment: Brilliant. Now I just hope they fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had a look at this on my computer. Problem seems to happen with any format I downloaded (tar.gz, .doc, .odt, .pdf). I checked the icon source in nautilus and it appears to be the wrong location (It errors and says "not found - Check spelling etc".).

As such, it is most probably a bug and should be reported. (To Google as Canonical do not support Chrome & Chromium)

Comment: Just an update to this problem, but after going through Fedora and Linux Mint, and using Gnome-Shell in Ubuntu, Fedora, and Linux Mint, I've noticed that this problem doesn't happen when I'm using Gnome-Shell at all on any of the OSes. It only occurs when I'm using Unity on Ubuntu, which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been filed in the chromium bug tracker at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102211

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be fixed manually on Ubuntu 11.10+ (maybe works on older distibution), simply by installing gnome-icon-theme-full.

1) Open terminal and paste below code:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full
```

2) Check icons on your download page in Google Chrome

```
chrome://downloads
```